# How can I get a custom gradle configuration onto the Gradle classpath container?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have a build.gradle file like:

```
configurations {
  provided
}
dependencies {
  compile ...
  provided ...
}
```

When I import the project into Eclipse with the STS Gradle plugin, only the compile conf dependencies show up under the "Gradle Dependencies" classpath container.

Is it possible to also have the provided conf get pulled in by the STS plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start this way you have two possibilities:

1. Quite likely you want to set up `compile` configuration as one that extends from `provided`. FYI there is some interesting discussion in [here](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784) and [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_best_define_dependencies_as_provided).

```
configurations {
   provided
   compile.extendsFrom provided
}
```

2. Another way is to apply eclipse plugin and add `provided` configuration to Eclipse classpath using `plusConfiguration` property as described [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html).

```
eclipse {
   classpath {
      plusConfigurations += [ configurations.provided ]
   }
}
```

Comment: compile.extendsFrom provided leads to the provided deps being marked as scope=compile in the generated POM. and the eclipse/classpath/plusConfigs is for generating .classpath files; I'm wanting to use the STS gradle plugin that provides a Gradle Dependencies classpath container.

Comment: STS plugin uses Gradle Tooling API that exposes information about Eclipse model. Both suggested customization are reflected in that model. It is a responsibility of STS plugin that is able to bundle dependencies extracted from this model into a classpath container entry.

Comment: You are exactly right! I'm sorry; I'd only seen that snippet in the context of "gradle eclipse" and so assumed STS wouldn't bother reading it. Thanks!